# Can Django template variables be used inside Jquery/Bootstrap to control collapse plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working `Django CB Views` and my template currently has form fields being rendered from an `UpdateView`. I've split the form and rendered the fields as individual elements. The form has 4 fields, 2 of which are currently under a bootstrap collapse plugin. This plugin is set to hide by default.

```
<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

But, if the 2 fields are populated, I want to set it to:

```
<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

This is what I have so far. My template:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.title %}
 {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.body %}

 <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" href="#advanced_panel" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="advanced_panel">Advanced</a>
 <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="advanced_panel">
     <div class="card card-block">
         {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.responder_name %}
         {% include 'partials/form_field.html' with field=form.response %}  #Only show if these two fields exist. 
     </div>
 </div>

 <a href="{% url 'backend_reviews' %}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Review" />
 <a href="{% url 'backend_reviews_delete' review.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Delete Review</a>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I do this, maybe using {% if %} and Jquery some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all I had to add for the class. It works.

```
class="panel-collapse collapse {% if review.responder_name and review.response %}in{%endif %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if form.response and form.responder_name %}
<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
{% else %}
<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
{% endif %}
```

or

```
<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse
{% if form.response and form.responder_name %} in{% endif %}">
```

Another option is to pass an additional boolean (e.g. `collapse_me`) to your template and then use that instead `form.*` like so:

`<div id="advanced_panel" class="panel-collapse collapse{% if collapse_me %} in{% endif %}">`

(of course you would need to create additional logic inside your view to set `collapse_me=True`/`collapse_me=False`)

Comment: Not working, the field is showing up even when not populated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "showing up"? Does the collapsible work? If not, see my edit.

Comment: The collapsible works, but I only want the collapsible to be shown if the two fields have values populated. If they are null or blank, then I want to hide the collapsible. When I do what you asked me to do, the collapsible was shown either way. It was not hidden when the field was blank

Comment: Well, that's not what you asked for in your original question.